# Is there a possible way to get a server's current moderation level?

Tags: python, discord, discord.py, command, bots

I'd like to get the server's current verification/moderation level (if possible).

Here is an example script:

```python
@bot.command()
async def verification(ctx):
  level = server.verification_level
  if level > 0: # 0 is for none, 1 for low, etc.
    await ctx.reply("You are secure!")
  else:
    await ctx.reply("You are not secure!")
```

[image: Screenshot of a moderation dialog box thingy]

Comment: Is the code not working as excepted? What does the code give you? Also: Where did you define `server`? (*As it should be `ctx.guild.verification_level`*)

Comment: Edit: It was just an example as to what I was looking for. I wasnt expecting it to work.

Comment: Well, then `ctx.guild.verification_level` is what you are looking for

Comment: are you sure its "verification_level"? It doesnt seem to work for me... (As said, i only said that as an example.)

Comment: The method should show the verification level. If you already tried it, why are you uploading an example and not your actual code so we can have a look at it?

Comment: I'm pretty sure you're not allowed to use integer comparisons like that. What's the error message (full traceback)?

Comment: For the third time I have no code for this. This is just what I guess it would look like if there was something like this. Im just asking how I would do it and I provide an example as to what I wanted to do with it.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Here is a solution for what you are trying to achieve:

```py
if ctx.guild.verification_level.name == "none":
    await ctx.reply("You are not secure")
else:
    await ctx.reply("You are secure!")
```

We simply check if the `name` of the `verification_level` is `"none"` and if that is the case, give the `"You are not secure"` message out.